# Calculate UPS and USPS Shipping Cost in Custom phtml page

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods, magento-1.9.3.6

I am using Magento 1.9.3.6.

I am adding Product Programmatically. I want to calculate the Shipping Cost in that phtml page. Like which is calculated in the `cart page` based on `quote`(Shown in the below)[image] while Customer enters the weight, Country(By Default US), State.

How to do this.

Below is the Screenshot.

[image]

**Update:**
I need Shipping Cost for `Ups` and `USPS` Shipping Methods.